# Passing attribute that can be "target" in JSF Composite Component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I created some composite components and need to pass attribute that could be used as "target" in Primefaces p:dataExporter and "datasource" in p:columnToggler.
First attr. "FormID" works as expected, but second one "tableID" do not. It is used under contextMenu. Code:

```
<composite:interface>
   <composite:attribute name="FormID"/>
   <composite:attribute name="tableID"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

<p:contextMenu for="#{cc.attrs.FormID}"> 
    <p:submenu label="Export">
        <p:menuitem value="Export to XLS" onclick="$('#exportToXLS').click()" />
    </p:submenu>

    <p:menuitem value="Columns" onclick="$('#toggler').click()" />
</p:contextMenu>

<p:commandLink id="toggler" type="button" />
    <p:columnToggler datasource="#{cc.attrs.tableID}" trigger="toggler" />

<p:commandLink id="exportToXLS" ajax="false" width="24">
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="#{cc.attrs.tableID}" 
        fileName="fileXls" />
</p:commandLink>

</composite:implementation
```

Here is github repo with project with code where  my problem occur: https://github.com/ntokarsk/PrimefacesTest

Comment: I found a solution to old primefaces versions 2.2; but it doesn't work with 5.3        https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1801

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I still don't know why previous solution didn't work - but this solution works. I have just read some old post and learn that menuitem is commandLink itself so I move p:dataExporter into menuItem and it works :D
1 thing is still missing - columnTrigger doesn't work. Any idea?

here's the code:

```
<composite:interface>
```

```
     <p:menuitem value="Export to XLS" ajax="false">
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target=":#{cc.attrs.FormID}:#{cc.attrs.tableID}"
           postProcessor="#{edycjaDanychCentrumBean.postProcessXLS}"
           fileName="daneCentrumDataTable" />
     </p:menuitem>

     <p:menuitem value="Export to PDF" ajax="false">
        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target=":#{cc.attrs.FormID}:#{cc.attrs.tableID}"
           fileName="daneCentrumDataTable" />            
     </p:menuitem>
  </p:submenu>

  <p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-close" />

  <p:menuitem id="toggler" value="Columns" icon="ui-icon-calculator">
     <p:columnToggler datasource=":#{cc.attrs.FormID}:#{cc.attrs.tableID}" trigger="toggler" />
  </p:menuitem>
  </p:contextMenu>
</composite:implementation>
```